# "unexpected identifier error" in pagination function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

although I passed the model variable in the parameters, it doesn't read them and gives a syntax error of unexpected identifier...

what is the issue ....any insight is much appreciated

```
function paginatedResults(model) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const limit = 20;

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const results = {};

    if (endIndex < await model.countDocuments().exec()) {
      results.next = {
        page: page + 1,
        limit: limit,
      };
    }

    if (startIndex > 0) {
      results.previous = {
        page: page - 1,
        limit: limit,
      };
    }
    try {
     results.results =await model.find().limit(limit).skip(startIndex).exec();
    res.paginatedResults = results;
    next();
} 
catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({message:error})
}
  };
}

module.exports=paginatedResults
```

Answer (score 0):

Add async at the start of the function call

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**The problem may be async await**

I have the same error

```
storeCtrl.getStores = async paginatedResults(Store), (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json(res.paginatedResults);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send("Bad request");
  }
};
```

If you look carefully there is an async coming to the function, for some reason if I remove async everything works fine... so my point is that it can't just be an async problem, maybe it's because a function is being called after having entered a property, parameter, attribute, etc before.